# GData TimeZoneProperty to Java TimeZone

Tags: java, timezone, google-calendar-api, gdata

Does anybody know how can I parse a [google.gdata.calendar.TimeZoneProperty](http://code.google.com/intl/es/apis/gdata/jsdoc/1.3/google/gdata/calendar/TimeZoneProperty.html#) to a [java.util.TimeZone](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html)?.

Thanks in advance.

Mikywan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it's quite simple to parse GData's TimeZoneProperty to java.TimeZone.

I leave you the code that solves it.

Enjoy!

Mikywan.

```
public static TimeZone parse(TimeZoneProperty pTimeZoneProperty) {
    TimeZone timeZoneRet = null;    

    if (pTimeZoneProperty != null && pTimeZoneProperty.getValue() != null && !pTimeZoneProperty.getValue().isEmpty()) {
        timeZoneRet = TimeZone.getTimeZone(pTimeZoneProperty.getValue());
    }

    return timeZoneRet;
}
```